# How do I change only part of a page when navigating?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have page like

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="page1.html">Page1</a>
        <a href="page2.html">Page2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="Container">
        Content
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When clicking the navigation, I want to get the page but with fixed ***header***. Just change the container's content and address bar or change page with fixed header

Just like Facebook with a fixed chat and header bar.

I tried a lot of ways like Ajax but I can't use it :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)'s `$.get()` and try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get(this.href, {}, function(data) {
            $('#container').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

This would replace the content of `#container` with whatever is behind the link in the navigation. It is then your responsibility to make sure, only the required content is in `page1.html`.

A better and more complex way to do this would be to have the full site content in `page1.html` and use some logic within the `success` function to extract only the required content.
This would fall back nicely for users without JavaScript etc.

Read up on jQuery's Ajax functionality and you should be able to work something out fairly quickly.